# Resize div on click and hide all other divs in parent.

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, image-gallery

I’m trying to create a gallery, but being totally new to jQuery I’m in a kind of deadlock.

I want to create a gallery consisting of several small pictures that expand to full width on click and return to its original on another. At the same time I want all the rest divs in parent wrap to hide while clicked image expands.  All that must be running smoothly and prettily. That’s what I can’t reach. 
All pics have .image class and each of them has class .one .two and so on. They are all under parent wrap.

```
$(".image").bind('click', function() {
     $(this).animate({width: "100%", height: "100%"}, 800);
$(".image").not(this).hide("slow");
});

$('.image').toggle(function(){
    $(this).animate({width: "100%", height: "100%"}, 800);    
}, function(){
    $(this).animate({width: "90px", height: "90px"}, 800);
    $(".image").not(this).show("slow");
});
```

The result of my efforts by now http://jsfiddle.net/baltar/TRuNv/4/

Good example of smoothness here http://css-tricks.com/examples/InfoGrid/

Also, it would be great to set up adjusting the height of parent div on the fly, so image of any proportions will fit. I’ve tried to set parent’s height to auto, but that didn’t work.

I realize that my question is to big to ask, but maybe at least anyone could advise which direction should I look to.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to either make a table with fixed row heights and column widths and put the images in cells or make all the divs absolutely positioned. Otherwise the other divs will move around like it does now. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following jQuery does *most* of what you request:

```
$(".image").bind('click', function() {
    var that = $(this), // caching the current element
        offsets = that.position(), // edited to use position() instead of offset()
        top = offsets.top,
        left = offsets.left,
        clone = that.clone(),
        parent = that.parent(), // caching the parent element
        width = parent.width(),
        height = parent.height();

    // adding the 'clone' element to the parent, and adding the 'clone' class-name    
    clone.addClass('clone').appendTo(parent).css({
        // positioning the element at the same coordinates
        // as the current $(this) element
        'top': top,
        'left': left
    }).animate({
        // animating to the top-left corner of the parent, and
        // to the parent's dimensions
        'top': 0,
        'left': 0,
        'width': width,
        'height': height
    }, 1000).click( // binding a click-handler to remove the element

    function() {
        // also fading the sibling elements back to full opacity
        $(this).fadeOut().siblings().animate({
            'opacity': 1
        }, 1000);
    }).siblings().animate({
        // fading-out the sibling elements
        'opacity': 0.1
    }, 1000);

});​
```

This requires the CSS:

```
.wrap {
    /* your other unchanged CSS, and: */
    position: relative;
}
.clone {
    position: absolute;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TRuNv/7/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
- [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).
- [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/).
- [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
- [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I'm trying to understand it now :) There is a problem with the fact that the enlarged images are cropped. They fit the height but cut the width in safari and chrome, and otherwise in IE. And when you click the increase is not coming from the same place, a little(differ in ie, safari and chrome) to the right. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yep! I'm not sure *why* this is happening (it's quite late in the UK...), but if you use [`position()`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TRuNv/7/) instead of `offset()` the clone seems to originate from the right position. =) (NB corrected the link...)

Comment: Cool! Thanks again! Won't bother you anymore )

Comment: Ha, *sorry!* That *really* wasn't the intent of my comment; I'm glad to have been of help. =)